# Getting values resulted from accessing the URL with query (php)

Tags: php, url

I have a URL like given below

[http://mydomain.com/wrt/search.php?org=125&assignedto[]=NULL&Search=req_assigned_to&state[]=New&state[]=Pending%3A+Installation&state[]=Pending%3A+More+Info&state[]=Assigned&state[]=Working&orgs[]=125](http://mydomain.com/wrt/search.php?org=125&assignedto%5b%5d=NULL&Search=req_assigned_to&state%5b%5d=New&state%5b%5d=Pending%3A+Installation&state%5b%5d=Pending%3A+More+Info&state%5b%5d=Assigned&state%5b%5d=Working&orgs%5b%5d=125)

i need to get the values of other required variables which results from accessing the above URL given in PHP..

Actually i should use this above mentioned link to access the form varaible values which will be displayed in that form resulted by execution of  some queries using the parameters passed through the link given above..i wont be using form concepts such but can use this link alone,as i dont have access to the required database so this link is the base to retrieve values ...

Please suggest how it can be done.Its of high urgency.

Comment: Please do some research.

Comment: an you elaborate a bit? Is your question on how to access the parameters in the url?

Comment: any problem with `$_GET` or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access URL parameter via `$_GET`, when you have this URL try for example:

`echo $_GET['Search'];` should output `req_assigned_to`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do but if I'm right you are looking for:

```
echo $_GET['org'];
```

This will echo 125. replace org with any other parameter in your url.

Read up on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: @ Robin                                                        Actually i should use this above mentioned link to access the form varaible values which will be displayed in that form resulted by execution of  some queries using the parameters passed through the link given above..i wont be using form conceptas such but can use this link alone,as i dont have access to the required database so this link is the base to retrieve values ...